# How connect to database to extract data and write pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle

I have to connect oracle database to extract data and write into pandas data frame.

All I have available with me is
**Hostname ,
Port,
Service Name**

```
import cx_Oracle
Hostname = 'XX.XX.X.XXX'
port = 1521
Service_Name = 'DPP2.kn.com'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(Hostname, port, Service_Name)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect('BA', 'PASSWORD', dsn_tns)
```

Its not working.How to fix this

Comment: Have you installed the Instant client ( the oracle client driver) and set `ORACLE_HOME` to the appropriate path ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cx_Oracle.connect` method as

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.connect(username+"/"+password+"@"+ Hostname+":"+port+"/"+Service_Name)
cursor = dsn_tns.cursor()
```

and then retrieve data through `cursor.execute()`

Comment: Getting database error  DP1-1047 : Cannot locate a 64 bit Oracle client  directory.

Comment: @pankaj the issue is obvious then ( 64-bit client needed )