# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:ORA-12504:TNS:listener was not given the service_name in connect _data

Tags: python, oracle

I want to connect python to oracle. I use cx_Oracle to do it. The code:

```
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@localhost')
```

and I get:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the
>   service_name in connect_data

How can I deal with it?

Comment: you can have a look at `tnsnames.ora` to verify `service_name`

Comment: I didn't set 'service_name' here. Should I set 'service_name'?@ Barbaros Özhan

Comment: perhaps you have `SID` inside `tnsnames.ora`, do you see that, if you see, try to test with that as service_name

Comment: I have 'service_name' inside 'tnsnames.ora', so how can I set the 'service_name' in my code

Comment: perhaps, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55432712/how-connect-to-database-to-extract-data-and-write-pandas-dataframe/55432838#55432838) may help

Comment: It works, thanks @Barbaros Özhan

Comment: you're welcome :) If it helped, you can try upvoting